# C# Best Practice for running Background Workers sequentially?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have UI that I want to keep responsive - I have two procedures that I want to run async.

There are two scenarios:

1. I just call Proc A
2. I call Proc A, then when that completes, call proc B.

Currently I keep a boolean ('procAWorking') that when I start worker A I set to 'true' and when Proc A's RunWorkerCompleted event is called, I set to 'false'.

For scenario 1, no problem.
For scenario 2, I call Proc A from a method, and then use a 'while' loop to wait until Proc A indicates it is done.

Is this an appropriate method?  Is there an understood better practice?

```
...
ProcA(); // method creates BW and calls RunWorkerAsync()

while(procAWorking)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

ProcB(); // method creates different BW and calls RunWorkerAsync()
```

Comment: Why not use Task and ContinueWith? You can chain them together then.

Comment: Surely you're blocking the UI while you wait for it to finish? I'd suggest you look at async / await and `Task.Run`.

Comment: Second Lloyd. Also look into SyncronizationContxt on the continuation task if you plan to update the ui.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you work with async/await it is actually quite easy to do what you want.

You need both procA and procB to be async methods:

```
async Task ProcA()
{
    //ProcA work here, delay to simulate work
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

async Task ProcB()
{
    //ProcB work here, delay to simulate work
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Then you can just call it like this:

```
async Task DoStuff()
{
    await ProcA();
    await ProcB();
}
```

Comment: this wont guarantee a responsive ui which is what OP said they need.

Comment: If he rewrites the methods to be properly async, then this will indeed make it possible to keep a responsive UI.

Comment: I've been considering  this which is why I asked the question, but what is the reason that this would be better than BW which I understand is specifically written to make it easy to keep UI's responsive..?

Comment: Because this make you code asynchronous while keeping it a easy to read as synchronous. That is the idea at least, and I find it to be mostly true. There are a number of pitfalls with Tasks though, such as deadlock when you don't expect them. Read this guys blog and you should be fine: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

If you already set a flag to `false` for `RunWorkerCompleted` handler, then why not start the second background processing at that time instead.

So only calls `ProcA` from your code and then call `ProcB` from `RunWorkerCompleted` of the first background worker...

Comment: I could - but I don't always call Proc B after Proc A, so I'd still be needing to have a switch - in this case it would be callProcB (true/false) passed in to the call ProcA call?

Comment: Well if you know before calling ProcA if ProcB should be called, then you can send that information through `RunWorkerAsync` argument and then from `DoWork` handler transfer that information to `e.Result` possibly taking into account local information... And then `RunWorkerCompleted` can check if it should continue with `ProcB`...